# Converting PHP code to C# code

Tags: c#, php

```
<?php 
$pwd = "test"; 
$crypted = base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1(utf8_encode($pwd)))); 
echo("$crypted"); 
?>
```

So I got this PHP code above and I am trying to convert it to C# code. I have tried the following, but it doesn't have the same output.

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");
            SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            var result = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
            string hex = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
            byte[] packH = PackH(hex);
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(packH);
```

and the Method:

```
  public static byte[] PackH(string hex)
        {
            if ((hex.Length % 2) == 1) hex += '0';
            var bytes = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
            {
                bytes[i / 2] =  Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

And because i don't have enough reputation to answer my own question i will write the answer here:D

```
It seems that i needed to do some extra things:D 

     public static string Crypt(string data)
            {
                SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
                byte[] computeHash = sha.ComputeHash(buffer);

                string delimitedHexHash = BitConverter.ToString(computeHash);
                string hexHash = delimitedHexHash.Replace("-", "");
                byte[] packH = PackH(hexHash);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(packH);
            }

            public static byte[] PackH(string hex)
            {
                if ((hex.Length%2) == 1) hex += '0';
                var bytes = new byte[hex.Length/2];
                for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    bytes[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
                }
                return bytes;
            }
```

Or even easyier

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("root"))));
```

Comment: Why don't you start compare by comparing values step by step and see exactly what fails?

Comment: Looks like you didnt implement an equivalent of the pack function, maybe this will help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ca080d6e-0707-4030-a3c7-462d5903b5f8

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in the PHP version you are also calling `pack` on the output of the SHA1 function, before you are base64 encoding.

If I interpret the PHP version correctly you are basically first doing a hex encoding of the output of the SHA1 hash and then you are Base64 encoding the hex encoded string - which is NOT the same as Base64 encoding the output of the SHA1 hash directly which is what is happening in the C# version..

Comment: Well, sorry it was a typo, but still not working

Comment: Thanks.. Your comment was spot on!